Forcing TDownloadURL.DownloadRawBytes to skip string conversion when no ContentType Header
I'm trying to use TDownloadURL.DownloadRawBytes from the Rest.Client unit to download a PDF file from an Amazon S3 bucket.
My problem seems to be an empty ContentType returned with the file. I don't control the server side and don't have any way to get them to correctly set the ContentType.
TRESTRequest.Execute looks at the returned context type, if it is empty then it forces the MimeKind to TMimeTypes.TKind.Text. That in turn forces the returned Bytes to be converted to a string.
There is a way to pass in a different string encoding, but not a way to force a MimeType or to skip the string conversion.
Without that when I Execute the request I get the following error:

Project raised exception class EEncodingError with message 'No mapping
for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page'.


Is there a different method I should be using?
Am I missing a way to force to binary or otherwise skip the string conversion?
Is there a TEncoding option that will never fail? I was looking for some type of hex encoding that could encode everything, but didn't see anything.


I would not expect DownloadRawBytes() to do any string conversion at all, given that it writes Response.RawBytes to the TStream you give it. If its converting the data, that is a very bad design decision on Embarcadero's part, and I would suggest filing a bug report with them. The HTTP spec is quite clear that unknown data should be treated as raw octets, not as text, if the type can't be guessed through inspecting the data (which TRESTClient doesn't do).

I think it's stupid that TRESTClient forcibly converts the raw data to a string up front before the caller even asks for it. They should have done it more dynamically. As a workaround, I would suggest using TRESTClient directly, then you can specify a FallbackCharsetEncoding and set to something like ISO-8859-1 or even CP437 to avoid the error, then simply ignore the Response.Content and use the Response.RawBytes as needed.

Seemed like a bad idea to me as well, thanks for confirming that I'm not crazy in this instance. I did file a bug report with Embarcadero. Both of your encoding suggestions worked for me.  I'll add an answer with my replacement function for DownloadRawBytes, however if you want to add an answer with your comments I'll mark that as accepted.

You can tell S3 to override some response headers in your request: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html look at the Overriding response header values through the request section. It doesn't work for anonymous requests however.

Here is my modified version of DownloadRawBytes. I needed the response saved to a file so it write is out directly instead of returning a stream.
Based on Remy's comment I set the FallbackCharsetEncoding, both CP437 and ISO-8859-1 worked for me.
procedure TMapRightIntegration.SaveAttachment(AUrl, AFileName: String);
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  Request: TRESTRequest;
  Client: TRESTClient;
  Response: TCustomRESTResponse;

begin
  Client := TRESTClient.Create(AUrl);
  try
    Request := TRESTRequest.Create(Client);
    Request.SynchronizedEvents := False;

    // We don't need the string, this encoding will ensure the 
    // conversion from binary will not fail on any byte.
    Client.FallbackCharsetEncoding := 'CP437';

    Request.Execute;
    Response := Request.Response;

    if Response.StatusCode >= 300 then
      raise ERequestError.Create(Response.StatusCode, Response.StatusText, Response.Content);

    if Response.RawBytes = nil then
      raise Exception.Create('RawBytes is nil');

    FileStream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmCreate);
    try
      FileStream.WriteBuffer(Response.RawBytes[0], Length(Response.RawBytes));
    finally
      FileStream.Free;
    end;

  finally
    Client.Free;
  end;
end;


Why ignoring the HTTP status codes 301, 302, 303, 307 and 308 which you could perfectly handle yourself?

@AmigoJack, no specific reason. That is the way DownloadRawBytes is currently handling errors and I just kept that without thinking about my options.

You should do FileStream.WriteBuffer(POINTER(Response.RawBytes)^, Length(Response.RawBytes)); assuming that RawBytes is a TBytes or ARRAY OF BYTE (dynamic array of BYTE). Otherwise you will get an access violation if/when it is empty (0 bytes).
